# GORM get method based on dependent criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I'm new to Groovy/Grails so this could be an easy question.  I have the feeling this is common code but I've spent a while and I can't find the right thing to Google.

I have a domain structure with several many to many relationships ( indicated by <--> )

Worker <--> Assembly Line <--> Part

The trick is that there are also 2 different one to many relationships on the same class...

Worker -> Inspection
Part -> Inspection

A part can be inspected many times, but there always has to be a person who does the inspection.

I'm in the Assembly Line controller and and I can do AssemblyLine.get(id) easy enough, but that will give me all inspections for the parts in that line.  I only want the inspection for the worker that I pulled from the session.

Is there an easy way to do this that I'm missing?  It feels like there should be.

Comment: I think if you gave Class A, B, C, and D real-world examples (eg Author - Book), it would make it easier to understand your question.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Hopefully the classes above make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use GORM, like

```
Inspection.findAllByWorkerAndPart(session.worker,somePart)
```

If you need more specific, please write down the domain classes with related properties.

Thanks.

Comment: This would only give me the parts that were inspected, right?  I want to start with an Assembly Line and display all of the parts on that line, not just the ones that were inspected by a worker.

Comment: Aha..this would give all the inspections not part. Actually which collection do you need? If you need parts then you can use:  ` Parts.findAllByAssemblyLineAndWorker(assemblyLine, worker) ` . Can give better suggestion if you share your domains and share which collections do you require.

Comment: I need the information starting with the Assembly Line.  Currently the code is written AssemblyLine.get(params.id).  This almost works, except it returns every inspection whereas I want to limit the inspections included.

Comment: I can post more code later, but currently I'm at work and since this is a personal project I don't have the code available on this machine.